# openslide_python-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, pip

I try to install openslide via a wheel since I want to analyze larger pictures.

I ran :

`python -c "import wheel.pep425tags as w
print(w.get_supported())"`
(to get the supported wheels for my platform)

and got this:

`[('cp36', 'cp36m', 'win_amd64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'win_amd64'), ('cp36', 'none', 'any'), ('cp3', 'none', 'any'), ...`

Based on this, I downloaded following file:

[openslide_python-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl](https://pypi.org/project/openslide-python/#files)

(Link refers to download destination and does not download the file of course)

When I now want to run:

`pip install openslide_python-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

this error occurs:

`ERROR: openslide_python-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Does anybody know why it doesn't work even if it tells me that the wheel should be supported?

Edit:
Using `Python 3.6.8` and pip `19.1.1`

Comment: What does `pip -V` return?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the python and pip version:
`python 3.6.8` 
`pip 19.1.1`
`pip -V` returns 

`pip 19.1.1 from c:\users\*user*\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: Then it's the wrong `pip` you're using - it's for conda's Python 3.7 which will of course fail on `cp36m` packages. Find out what the correct `pip` command for your Python 3.6 installation is (looks like you're on Windows, so `where pip` and check the multiple paths returned), it may be either `pip3.6` or `py -3.6 -m pip` or something else, depending on what installer you used to install Python 3.6.